# Changing Image Source code behind by binding wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, image, binding

I'm trying to change an image source by clicking on something.

my .xaml

```
<Canvas Name="img_Canvas" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
        <Image Source="{Binding ImageType_Source}" Name="autoImage" Margin="5"/>
```

my .cs

```
private string _ImageType_Source;
        public string ImageType_Source
        {
            get { return _ImageType_Source; }
            set { 
                _ImageType_Source = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ImageType_Source");
            }
        }

        public exImage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
```

So when I click on e.g Ellipse, I want to change the image.

```
private void Ellipse_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            ImageType_Source = "/ANKE_Test;component/imagesFolder/Bild_Getriebe.jpg";
            string test = autoImage.Source.ToString();
```

After changing the source the PropertyChangedEvent is fired with PropertyChanged = null but with the new source. Unfortunately the source in the image is still the old one and is not changing.

Comment: if `PropertyChanged == null` that implies that nothing is listening to the event so the UI can't react and change. Does your .cs implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: yes it does implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: Shouldn't the code be `if (this.PropertyChanged != null) this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));` rather than `OnPropertyChanged(name);`. You're not firing the event.

Comment: Thank you, totally forgotten !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with INotifyPropertyChanged I usually make my own NotifyPropertyChanged method like this:

```
private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info) {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
```

Did you do this to with your OnPropertyChanged method?